# Objective-c: Use predicate with an object

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I have a search bar for my table view and until now I used a predicate to check if the data array contains the search bar value. But now there are objects in my data array and now I don't know how to use the predicate. Here is my code:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [cd] %@", self.controller.searchBar.text];

NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < [self.data count]; i++) {
    Student *student = [[Student alloc] initWithIdentifier:[[self.data objectAtIndex:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row] objectForKey:@"id"] name:[[self.data objectAtIndex:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row] objectForKey:@"name"] is_public:[[self.data objectAtIndex:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row] objectForKey:@"is_public"] password:[[self.data objectAtIndex:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row] objectForKey:@"passwort"]];
    [temp addObject:student];
}

self.results = [temp filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Now it compares the search bar value with the object. But it should compare the search bar value with object.name. How can I do this?

EDIT:

The Student code:

```
@implementation Student

- (id)initWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier name:(NSString *)name is_public:(NSString *)is_public password:(NSString *)password {
    self= [super init];

    if( self ) {
        self.identifier = identifier;
        self.name = name;
        self.is_public = is_public;
        self.password = password;
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSDictionary*)writableRepresentation {
    NSMutableDictionary *writableRepresentation= [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:4];

    [writableRepresentation setValue:self.identifier forKey:@"Identifier"];
    [writableRepresentation setValue:self.name forKey:@"Name"];
    [writableRepresentation setValue:self.is_public forKey:@"is_public"];
    [writableRepresentation setValue:self.password forKey:@"password"];

    return writableRepresentation;
}

+ (Student*)studentFromDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionaryRepresentation {
    return [[Tipprunde alloc] initWithIdentifier:[dictionaryRepresentation valueForKey:@"Identifier"] name:[dictionaryRepresentation valueForKey:@"Name"] is_public:[dictionaryRepresentation valueForKey:@"is_public"] password:[dictionaryRepresentation valueForKey:@"password"]];
}
@end
```

It don't seem to work with SELF.name. I get the following error:

> -[Student objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...

Comment: SELF.name to try. if your  temp value like this [@{name:hari},@{name:hari},@{name:hari}];

Comment: print your temp values

Comment: What is `Student`? What are its properties? Which one exactly are you trying to filter `@property name`? If yes, try with `@"SELF.name contains[cd] %@"`?

Comment: SELF.name don't seem to work. Just look at my edits.

Comment: It should works. I just tried with a simple objects, and it worked. Your error doesn't seem to be an issue because of the predicate. Usually, with filtering and `NSPredicate` you get an error `[<ClassOfTheObject 0x17624270> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key theKeyYourAreLookngFor.`, where `theKeyYourAreLookngFor` is in our case `name`. I don't understand why it's calling for `objectForKey:`. From what inherits `Student`?

Comment: What is `self.data`? An array of NSDictionary? The predicate format should be "name contains [cd] %@".